# Update schema version in order to BackUp/Restore

Tags: 2013, backup, restore, schema, version

I have two different SharePoint farms. One's schema version is 15.0.4420.1017 and the new one is using 15.0.4569.1000.

The oldest is hosted on W2008R2 (all-in-one server), and the new one is hosted on W2012R2 with a dedicated sql server.

I would like to backup/restore a site collection (already know PS way), but I have a schema version problem. I'd backuped up from W2008R2 to W2012R2.

Can I just download this kb http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2956166 and install it on both servers ? Or is there any thoughts I should have before updating this ?

I must say that this is a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply Service Pack 1 on the production environment that is running the RTM version. No patches are needed before applying SP1.

Download the correct type (Foundation, server or project server) for your farm and apply the service pack to all the servers in the farm, and then run the configuration wizard on each one of the servers. So if you have SharePoint 2013 Foundation, install the SP1 for foundation.

SP1 mark 2 is the correct service pack as the first version of SP1 had a bug in it and was later pulled back by Microsoft.

And be aware, while installing updates, the SharePoint timer service is stopped = SharePoint is unavailable during the time the updates are applied. So I recommend doing this during after work hours.

[SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346)

Comment: In order to be able to restore my site collection, would you advise me to use a Hex editor as mentionned here : http://sadomovalex.blogspot.fr/2013/11/how-to-restore-site-collection-from.html to hard code schema version

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: No, i would not tinker with any backup and then restore it to a production environment.. it's like asking for trouble and i think that would put your farm in a unsupported state. It's better to have both your environments on the same version instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarification. Last question, when I's have installed SP1 Mark2 on my W2008R2, I'd be able to directly install the March CU 15 (KB2956166) update ? (on both sharepoint server btw)

Comment: Is it a standalone server or is it a farm with multiple servers? Remember to apply the service pack to all your application and web front end server (not the sql server). While you could do that theoretically (a CU contains all updates in the previous CU's up to the latest service pack), I would only apply a CU if something in your environment is broken and a CU can fix it.

Comment: Ok, the old one is standalone, while the new farm is 2 app server and 1 sql. Ok, I don't really need CU Update, the SP1 Mark2 should be enough as I just need to backup/restore a site collection, so I need the same schema version. I'll install SP1 on my standalone so. Thanks @user19952 !